# How to add dependency to the boot class path?

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, alpn

I'm trying to add the `alpn-boot` dependency to the boot class path. The following should work in the pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.alpn.path>${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/${jetty.alpn.version}/alpn-boot-${jetty.alpn.version}.jar</jetty.alpn.path>
    <argLine.bootcp>-Xbootclasspath/p:${jetty.alpn.path}</argLine.bootcp>
    <jetty.alpn.version>8.1.6.v20151105</jetty.alpn.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>get-alpn-boot</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>get</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty.alpn</groupId>
                <artifactId>alpn-boot</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.alpn.version}</version>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, it definitely isn't being added to the boot class path. I'm running my application on Pivotal Web Services. Could it be to do with that? Or is there something wrong with my pom.xml file?

Comment: What do you mean "adding `alpn-boot` to the boot classpath"? If we're talking about the server running the application, Maven can't help you there.

Comment: It's from here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.8.v20150217/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-starting.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying. You want to add a dependency when you servers starts. If you're starting it with a Maven Jetty plugin, then post its configuration in your question. Otherwise, you'll have to add it to the startup script.

Comment: Ok, I dont think I can add it to the startup script because I'm running it on Pivotal Web Services and haven't found a way to do that yet. I haven't used the Maven jetty plugin either.. The way I'm doing it is following the instructions from this java library: https://github.com/relayrides/pushy and using their pom.xml as an example. It uses something called netty. I can post my whole pom.xml config if you'd like?

Comment: I tried googling "Pivotal Web Services start command" and got: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#options.